# After minification: Multiple directives [uibTab, uibTab] asking for transclusion

Tags: angularjs, angular-directive, grunt-contrib-uglify

I have a working AngularJS app, but the build version (Grunt concat, uglify) shows this error multiple times in ALL my views:

```
Error: [$compile:multidir] Multiple directives [seatChart, seatChart] asking for new/isolated scope on: <div class="seatChart" data="model.seatChart">
```

After this error occures, I get a similar error for "[uib-tab, uib-tab]" in other views as well.

I don't know which code to post (the app.min.js won't help and the not-minified version works) - I just hope that anybody has had the same issue and knows how to solve it.

**Edit**

I have now removed everything from my controller and from the html - but I still get the same error in the minified version. If I remove the directive I get the same error with [uib-tab, uib-tab].

It seems to be a timing issue, because when I reload the page sometimes it works.

Comment: You refer to the minified version specifically here is it working fine without minification? The error basically means the uib-tab directive is asking for the contents in the tag but there is none, if the html minifier eliminates all the whitespace uib-tab would have nothing to transclude you could either add an empty element to the uib-tabs or turn off the whitespace minification for html.

Comment: I have also tried the original html files (not-minified html, but minified js) - still the same. But I have found out, that this problem seems to be caused by my own directive, which I put INTO one of the ui-tabs in one of my views. No idea what's happening...

Comment: Hmm yeah in general the error is saying it's trynig to use the contents to insert them somewhere into the directives template but keep the original scope, that's what transcluding does, basically lets you make a "frame" component where people can use the directive but put their own stuff inside.  Would be helpful to see what your directive is doing but guess is it somehow ends up emptying out the uib-tab while the uib-tab is processing.

Comment: Thanks shaunhusain, I have updated my question

Answer (score 0):

Short answer: My files are loaded twice.

Long answer: I am using the build process of an older version of the Clip-Two Admin Theme. The build process concatenates all JS files as it should. However there is an on-demand loader in the router which loads JS files based on the loaded view as well (the same files which are concatenated). So in the end all scripts are loaded twice which leads to the said problem.